# How does __declspec exactly work?

Tags: c++, dll

I've heard that when linking dynamically you need a stub library that has __declspec(dllexport) for every function and variable that you want from the DLL. Now my question is: How does it work exactly? Is it a Visual Studio or C++ keyword and how does it locate the functions and variables from the DLL by name since they are 1s and 0s (machine instructions) for the CPU? And where can I find more information about __declspec and more detail about how it works and what it does?

Comment: You don't *have* to have it, there are other ways to tell the linker which functions need to be exported (.def file, /export linker option).  It is just a very convenient way.  It is non-standard since the C++ language specification does not recognize the concept of modules.  They've been talking about it for the past 5 years but it isn't going to make it for C++17.

Comment: I have add a comment to the other question with links to the MSDN.